# Fetch the second record from the file using the Pig

Tags: apache-pig

My data is like this:

```
(Alicia,2,Maths,Chemistry,Physics)
(Mac,2,Maths,Chemistry,Botany)
(Hardik,6,Maths,Chemistry,Zoology)
(Maneesh,9,Hindi,Chemistry,Physics)
```

I want to make a relation which will contain only the second record data, (Mac,2,Maths,Chemistry,Botany) and then I want to perform further operations. 
I tried using LIMIT command but i will get some records not the specific record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use filter for getting specific records.Assuming you have a relation A with the sample dataset, then the below Pig statement will get you the record you are looking for.

```
B = FILTER A BY (A.$0 == 'Mac');
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the job.

```
a = load '<your data>';
b = rank a;
c = filter b by $0 == 2;
```

Hope this help!